# Organizing objects and libraries

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, frameworks, organization

I've been creating a small number of libraries / classes from scratch in php. I come from a codeigniter background, and I'm trying to make some libraries with similar functionality. I keep running into issues regarding objects.

Is the best way to create a super object `$this` somehow? My main issue is that I've created a view object and I run a function called `load` which looks like so:

```
class View {

        public function __construct() {
        }

        public function load($file = NULL, $data = array()) {
                if($file) {
                        $file .= '.php';
                        if(file_exists($file)) {
                                // Extract variables BEFORE including the file
                                extract($data);
                                include $file;
                                return TRUE;
                        } else {
                                echo 'View not found';
                                return FALSE;
                        }
                } else {
                        return FALSE;
                }
        }
}
```

Then in my php file, I have at the top `include 'libraries.php';` which looks like:

```
include 'database.php';
include 'view.php';
include 'input.php';
include 'form.php';

$config = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database'
);

$database = new Database($config);
$view = new View();
$input = new Input();
$form = new Form();
```

From the file which I included the libraries, I am able to write something like `$form->value('name');` without errors. However, if I do something like this:

`$view->load('folder/index', array('var_name' => 'var_value'));` then from the `folder/index.php` file I can access `$var_name` just fine, but not `$form->value('name');`. I get errors such as `Call to a member function value() on a non-object in ...`

My question is how can I organize my libraries and classes in a way that will be reusable. I don't want to use a front loader (an `index.php` file that everything runs through first). This may be an issue with the way I wrote my classes, but I imagine it's a larger issue regarding where things are located etc.

Comment: use namespaces (at least fake ones) and autoloading

Comment: `I don't want to use a front loader (an index.php file that everything runs through first)` I'm really curious why?

Comment: You could use a Registry to access all your objects everywhere altough I don't recommend it. Another option is to do some dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Put your library/class files in a common directory.  Something like:

```
 www
 |_includes
 | |_classes
 | | |_view.php
 | |_config
 |   |_database.php
 |_other_folder
   |_index.php
```

You can then set a common include path in your .htaccess file to this "includes" directory:

```
php_value include_path .:/path/to/www/includes
```

Then the other_folder/index.php file just needs something like:

```
require_once('config/database.php');
require_once('classes/view.php');
```